# Ending non-daemon threads when shutting down an interactive python session

Tags: python, python-multithreading

Please consider the code below:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import threading
import time

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._quit_flag = False
    def run(self):
        while not self._quit_flag:
            print("Thread is alive!")
            time.sleep(0.500)
    def request_quit(self):
        self._quit_flag = True

mt = MyThread()
mt.start()
```

After saving this as 'test.py' and running 'python3 -i test.py', I get an interactive session, where the thread regularly prints the "Thread is alive!" message.

When I press control-D or run exit(), the python3 process does not terminate because the thread is still running. I want to fix that.

However, *I do not want to make the thread a daemon thread* -- I want to be able to end / join the thread properly, because in the real-life case I'm solving, I want to terminate a network connection nicely.

Is there a way to do this? For example, is some hook available that is executed after the REPL loop terminates, just prior to the exit of the main thread?

Comment: Are you aware of `atexit`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I found a way to do this myself.

Looking at the Python source-code, it turns out that at shutdown, Python attempts to join() all non-daemonic threads before completing the shutdown of the process. Which sort-of makes sense, except that this would be much more useful if there were a documented way to signal those threads. Which there isn't.

However, it *is* possible to re-implement the join() method of one's own class derived from Thread, which can that serve as a way to notify the subthread that it is supposed to shut itself down:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._quit_flag = False
    def __del__(self):
        print("Bye bye!")
    def run(self):
        while not self._quit_flag:
            print("Thread is alive!",  threading.active_count(), threading.main_thread().is_alive())
            for t in threading.enumerate():
                print(t.is_alive())
            time.sleep(0.500)
    def request_quit(self):
        self._quit_flag = True

    def join(self):
        self.request_quit()
        super().join()
```

However, this way of addressing the issue is a pretty much a hack, and it ignores the following passage from the 'threading' module docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html):

> The Thread class represents an activity that is run in a separate
>   thread of control. There are two ways to specify the activity: by
>   passing a callable object to the constructor, or by overriding the
>   run() method in a subclass. **No other methods (except for the
>   constructor) should be overridden in a subclass. In other words, only
>   override the __init__() and run() methods of this class**.

It does, however, work beautifully.

Comment: This is actually quite useful. It probably should be avoided, but if the program is about to exit anyway, it would not matter even if it broke something.

Comment: Could we submit this to the python developers for consideration? Allowing join to be overwritten sounds like a useful feature unless that would break something we aren't seeing (like on windows?)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work anymore since Python 3.7.4. The "threading" modules'  _shutdown method was changed and doesn't call join() anymore. Sigh.

Comment: I've made a comment on the PR that introduced this change: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/13948

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this would be acceptable, but the only way I can see around your problem is to start the interactive console from your script instead of with `-i` flag. Then you would be able to carry on with your program to do the exit, after you terminate your interactive session:

```
import threading
import time
from code import InteractiveConsole

def exit_gracefully():
    print("exiting gracefully now")
    global mt
    mt.request_quit()
    mt.join()


class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._quit_flag = False
    def run(self):
        while not self._quit_flag:
            print("Thread is alive!")
            time.sleep(0.500)
    def request_quit(self):
        self._quit_flag = True

mt = MyThread()
mt.start()
InteractiveConsole(locals=locals()).interact()
exit_gracefully()
```

This you would execute without `-i` flag, only as

```
python3 test.py
```

It would still give you the interactive console as with `python -i`, but now the script executes `exit_gracefully()` after the interactive shell exits.

Comment: I appreciate your proposed workaround, but unfortunately in my real-life case this will not work; I need a solution that doesn't involve starting a dedicated interpreter.

Comment: I was afraid of some kind of a limitation there, thought to offer the solution anyway. Glad you were able to sort out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you can do this is to register a cleanup function using `atexit` and set your thread as a daemon, eg:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import threading
import time
import atexit

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # this ensures that atexit gets called.
        self.daemon = True
        self._quit_flag = False

    def run(self):
        while not self._quit_flag:
            print("Thread is alive!")
            time.sleep(0.500)
        print("cleanup can also go here")

    def request_quit(self):
        print("cleanup can go here")
        self._quit_flag = True


mt = MyThread()
def cleanup():
    mt.request_quit()
    mt.join()
    print("even more cleanup here, so many options!")

atexit.register(cleanup)
mt.start()
```

Comment: No that doesn't work. The atexit routines are called after the Python shutdown procedure attempts to join all living non-daemonic threads, which blocks if they don't terminate.

Comment: I was quite explicit that I didn't want to do that in my question.

Comment: I believe you said "I want to be able to end / join the thread properly, because in the real-life case I'm solving, I want to terminate a network connection nicely." ...

You have so many options for terminating your network connection ... making this thread a daemon doesn't prevent you from join it ...

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, but it quite literally doesn't answer my question, which is: "Ending non-daemon threads when shutting down an interactive python session".

Comment: "Is there a way to do this? For example, is some hook available that is executed after the REPL loop terminates, just prior to the exit of the main thread?"

-- There is a hook that's executed after the REPL, before the main thread exists, let me see if I can find what it's called :).

Comment: I was aware of atexit(). It doesn't help with non-daemonic threads.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171668/discussion-between-bi-rico-and-reddish).

Comment: No thanks, I don't think there's much more to be said.

I do appreciate your proposal, I hadn't thought about circumventing the Python shutdown process by making the thread a daemon, and then treating it as a non-daemon thread afterwards. I think it's a hack, and it's a matter of taste whether your hack is better or worse than mine, I think (my hack involves overriding join()).

Comment: Oh and I wrote such a nice, politic message in the chat ... now you'll never see it (not sarcasm).

Comment: For what it's worth, I did mark your answer as useful, even if it doesn't technically answer my question. It does provide an alternative approach.

Comment: I think it's too bad that python doesn't want you to override join, it seems like a useful thing to be able to do. I don't think using `atexit` is a hack, but if you want to argue the point it'll have to be some other time, I'm going to bed.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new shutdown thread in the background:

```
import threading
import time

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._quit_flag = False
    def run(self):
        while not self._quit_flag:
            print("Thread is alive!")
            time.sleep(0.500)
        print("shutting down.")
    def request_quit(self):
        self._quit_flag = True

mt = MyThread()
mt.start()

# Shutdown thread
threading.Thread(
    target=lambda: threading.main_thread().join() or mt.request_quit()
    ).start()
```