# doing something before thread exits

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a class that uses a worker thread to offload work into the background. The class inherits threading.Thread so the class itself is the worker thread. It has a number of functions that communicate with the worker thread including shutting it down.

Problem now is that sometimes I get an exception in the main code and the programs exits without ever calling the worker.shutdown() method. Python then ends the main thread and waits for the worker thread to finish, which it never does.

How can I terminate the worker thread when the main thread dies?

Comment: How does it help you to inherit from `threading`?

Comment: It doesn't help with anything. It's just one way of using threading.

Answer (score 1):

The arguably cleaner way would be to add exception handling to your main code and call `worker.shutdown()` if an exception is caught that you consider severe enough to warrant termination of the program.

Another solution is to flag the worker as daemon thread before starting them (see Hannu's answer). Please be aware that this will ungracefully terminate the worker.

From the docs:

> Daemon threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown. Their resources (such
>   as open files, database transactions, etc.) may not be released
>   properly.

Comment: Adding exception handling would be difficult to ensure, require extra work for the user of my module. I was hoping more for something like atexit.register but one that works for threads.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow in that case [sys.excepthook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) might be what you are looking for. Or rather overwriting sys.exceptohook

Answer (score 0):

Set the worker thread as daemonic.

```
f = threading.Thread(.....)
f.daemon = True
f.start()
```

Now your threads will be killed if your main program exits for any reason.

Comment: That won't do the necessary cleanup that worker.shutdown() triggers since the threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown.

Comment: At your own risk you can take a look at the OP's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50486083/ending-non-daemon-threads-when-shutting-down-an-interactive-python-session/50487402#50487402   It does an override of `Thread.join()` explicitly forbidden by Python documentation, but apparently it seems to work. Maybe this could work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `atexit` module:

http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html

It lets you execute a callable before your script exits

```
import atexit

def exit_handler():
    print('exiting program')
    worker.shutdown()

atexit.register(exit_handler)
```

Just be aware that this works great for normal termination of the script, but it won't get called in all cases (e.g. fatal internal errors).

Comment: It also won't be called until all threads exit iirc.