# How to kill a non daemon thread when closing the program in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

What is the proper way of killing a non daemon thread? I have program that is connected (asyncio) to an API and constantly receiving data from the server, this connection must run in a "normal" thread because if I set it to daemon it no longer works. The problem right now is, this connection remains open if I close the program. I can implement a signal to stop the thread when the exit button is clicked, but what if the program is closed in the task manager?

I guess my question is, does the program leave behind (after its compiled to an exe) the running thread if it is not closed with the button click? Or it will be closed despite I still see the thread running in the Visual Studio Code console if I click the exit button?

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50486083/ending-non-daemon-threads-when-shutting-down-an-interactive-python-session

Comment: When a process is killed, all threads in the process will be killed along with it.  (They have to be, because without the process's memory-space they have no way to continue running). I suspect that what you are doing when you "close the program" is actually just closing a window; the process must still be running (windowless) in order for your thread to keep running.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. There are many ways to close the program, I can prepare for some of them, but what about the rest? Is the "windowless" thread will run indefinitely? How can I terminate it without a daemon threat?